# Did I need to make the coordinate conversion?

Tags: mongodb

The spatial reference of my data is based on BaiDu Map,now I'd like to create a 2dsphere index.so Did I need to make the coordinate conversion from the spatial reference of BaiDu Map to WGS84?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The [2dsphere index overwiew](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) in MongoDB documentation seems to say so:

> The default datum for an earth-like sphere is WGS84. Coordinate-axis order is longitude, latitude.

What is important to remember is that your location data need to include geometry data.

- You can't create a 2dsphere index on:

  ```
  location : { coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] }
  ```
- But you can on:

  ```
  location : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] }
  ```

Comment: My question is " Is it necessary to make transform spatial reference from other spatial reference to WGS-84 ".I create a 2dsphere index successfully!  Thanks